# How to find a position in the FlowDocument where style is changed

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

I have a *FlowDocument* instance from WPF *RichTextBox*. I have to find all places in the *FlowDocument* where style is changed.

Incomming parameters:

- **doc** of type *FlowDocument* - document for analysis
- **beginPoint** and **endPoint** of type *TextPointer* - begin and the end of the range for analysis from the **doc**

Returning data:

- *TextPointer[]* which represents the list of locations in the **doc** where changes of style detected

Sample of text for analysis: "Welcome **to *the*** real world!" There are four chages of style: "Welcome" (normal), "to" (bold), "the" (bold italic), "real" (italic), "world!" (normal)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*FlowDocument* contains collection of *Blocks*. Each Block can be of *Paragraph* type. *Paragraph* contains *Inlines* properties. Every change of the style is an *Inline* instance that has *ContentBegin* and *ContentEnd*.

So final code for whole document should looks like below:

```
public TextPointer[] ExtractStyleChanges(FlowDocument doc)
{
    var result = new List<TextPointer>();
    foreach(var p in FlowDocument.Blocks.OfType<Paragraph>())
        foreach(var i in p.Inlines)
        {
            result.Add(i.ContentBegin);
        }
    return result.ToArray();            
}
```

This method can be upgraded with BeginPoint and EndPoint merkers.